# No update on the PDF when clicking "Quick Build"

Tags: pdf

I am making changes on my project but unfortunately when clicking "quick build" nothing changes, there is no update on the pdf. I have configurated the quick build command (Latex + dvips + ps2pdf + View  PDF). Did I miss something? I used to work with TexShop and clicking on Compile directly gave me an updated PDF. I would like to have the same here...

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where is "here"? Which application are you referring to? Which OS do you use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.